# Regular expression $text =~ s{\W}{}g; compiles in Perl what does it do?

Tags: dart, perl

I would appreciate it if anyone could give me some hints on what this statement does in Perl?

```
$text =~ s{\W}{}g;
```

My guess is it should match any non-word pattern but I'm not sure. It is part of a correctly functioning Perl program.

Can you provide an equivalent in Dart or Python to help me understand?

Comment: The equivalent Dart would be `text = text.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\W"), "");`. Which is inefficient, I'd recommend `text = text.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\W+"), "");` instead.

Comment: It was my mistake, I do apologize.  I am new here and  haven't quite figure out editing/correcting questions responses.  Correction perl compiles the expressions and runs it well

Answer (score 1):

The `s` means a substitution. It substitutes any non-word (i.e. non-identifier) character with nothing. The `g` modifier means it happens globally, i.e. everywhere (without it, only the first such character would be removed).

The `=~` operator binds the substitution to the variable `$text`, i.e. the contents of the variable is changed.

```
perl -e '$text = "a-1_b?2#"; $text =~ s{\W}{}g; print $text'
a1_b2
```